# Memory management c

Tags: c, free

So I know mallocs apply to the heap and not the stack.

I have a few questions:

Does any of this code get allocated or freed?

I don't see any free statements so I assume nothing is being freed so there is a memory leak correct?

Just for curisoity, if I try to free ptr, it crashes. If I try to free handle it works fine though.

```
  int num;
        int *ptr;
        int **handle;

        num = 14;
        ptr = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        handle = &ptr;
        *ptr = num;
        ptr = &num;
        handle = (int **)malloc(1 * sizeof(int **));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this code allocates memory, using the `malloc` call. You are seeing a crash when you try to free `ptr` at the end though because it is being reassigned to `&num`, which is allocated on the stack and cannot be free'd. Not only does it not make sense to de-allocate a stack variable (since it will be discarded on function exit anyway), but it's also not legal to do so since it has not been explicitly allocated. You can still free `handle` because it still points to the heap-local storage it was allocated.

To answer your other question, yes, there has been a memory leak. Additionally, because `ptr` has been set to point somewhere else, it's now impossible to free the original memory it pointed to since you no longer know the original address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it allocates memory using `malloc` which isn't freed so there is a leak. You've overwritten the address of the malloced memory in `ptr` with the address of `num` so you can't free that. The address of the initial malloced memory is lost, so that's a leak.

Answer (score 1):

If no free is done, then there's a memory leak. (check it with `valgrind`)

You can't free `ptr` because it points to a stack variable memory area (look at the instruction `ptr = &num;`) that can't be freed.